# Setting up a comparison to make one thing look appealing

Tags: word-choice

Is there a term for the (unethical) sales practice of:

- Customer requests product of a certain level of quality
- Salesperson provides two options.
- Option 1 is clearly inadequate, falling well and obviously short of the requirement
- Option 2 is also inadequate, but far superior to option 1
- You pick Option 2 as in comparison it appears to be the best choice

Presumably this allows the salesperson to unload products at a higher price than they were really worth.

I think the word "foist" has a similar idea in mind but I am not sure if it is really specific to this situation. Also I do not think this is a "bait and switch".

Comment: Is the unethical concealment of Option 2's inadequacy necessary for the meaning you want to convey?

Comment: @Spencer I would not say that *concealment* is necessary. I think rather that the use of Option 1 to artificially lower expectations is the key element. In such a circumstance I think a very objective customer could recognize that Option 2 is still not up to their requirements.

Comment: In general English you might make a case for something like "deception" or "dissimulation" or "dissembling", for "disingenuousness"…

Having not-too-long-ago revisited standard sales training specifically for: "Customer requests product of a certain level of quality" I suggest it doesn't matter whether that kind of subterfuge is recommended or banned… it's just not recognised except as above.